# Get data from 2 years into one result row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT BC_PID, Year, Period, 
CASE WHEN Year = 2017 THEN SUM(Allin+Basis+Entry+IFNULL(3CXUsers, 0)) END as '2017', 
CASE WHEN Year = 2018 THEN SUM(Allin+Basis+Entry+IFNULL(3CXUsers, 0)) END as '2018'  
FROM ext_partnertotals WHERE
(Year = '2018' OR Year = '2017') AND Period = 6
GROUP BY BC_PID, Year
```

The result is this:
[image]

Now I want to have the 2 rows for one `BC_PID` into one row.
So that I have the numbers for 2017 and 2018 for each `BC_PID` on one row.
I currently have the totals on 2 rows.

It should give:

```
  BC_PID |Period|2017 |2018
   2.001 |6     |1.744|2.444
 100.003 |6     |0    |0
```

Check this SQLfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c9b5/1

Comment: Take the year out of the `select` list and the `group by`

Comment: @cf_en then 2018 is NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweaked your fiddle slightly:

```
SELECT BC_PID, Period,
SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2017 THEN Allin+Basis+Entry+IFNULL(3CXUsers, 0) ELSE 0 END) as '2017',
SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2018 THEN Allin+Basis+Entry+IFNULL(3CXUsers, 0) ELSE 0 END) as '2018'
FROM ext_partnertotals
WHERE (Year = '2018' OR Year = '2017') AND Period = 6
GROUP BY BC_PID, Period
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT BC_PID, Year, Period, 
CASE WHEN Year IN (2017,2018) 
   THEN SUM(Allin+Basis+Entry+IFNULL(3CXUsers, 0)) END as '2017_8'
FROM ext_partnertotals 
WHERE (Year = '2018' OR Year = '2017') 
AND Period = 6 
GROUP BY BC_PID, Year
```